# Javascript: Adding all elements but those in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I have an array of column indexes that looks like, for example, [2, 4, 5] and an object with string value keys ranging from "0" through "6".

I want to create a new array containing all elements from my original object except those with keys matching any value in my column index array.  This is how I'm doing it currently but I'm not happy with it:

```
const convertObjectToArray = (columnIndexes, rowObject) => {
    return Object.keys(rowObject).map(key => {
        let rowValue = '';
        if (columnIndexes.indexOf(parseInt(key)) === -1) {
            rowValue = rowObject['' + key];
        }
        return rowValue;
    });
};
```

Perhaps there is a very simple, straightforward way of doing this and I'm just missing it?

Comment: Could you give a sample input and output?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter( k => columnIndices.indexOf(parseInt(k)) >= 0).map( k => obj[k])`

Comment: Note that your current approach doesn't technically filter out the other elements; it replaces them with empty strings (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @zinfandel: Yes, good catch and an important point.  The array I return should have the same number of elements in it as the original object.

Comment: In that case, your solution is already quite concise. As others have noted, you can replace the single `if` with a ternary expression: `return columnIndices.indexOf(parseInt(k)) >= 0 ? '' : obj[k]`.

Comment: @zinfandel and all, thanks for the help.  This is what I ended up with:

```return Object.keys(rowObject).map(columnKey => {
        return hiddenColumnIndexes.indexOf(+columnKey) >=0 ? '' : rowObject['' + columnKey];
});```

Comment: @katherine you can leave away that `{ return ... }` as well as `''+ columnKey`, columnKey stays a string all the time

Comment: @Jonasw: I did remove the `''` in front of `columnKey` but found I can't get rid of the `return` and have my code still work.

Comment: @kateelliot you need to get rid of the `{..}` as well than

Comment: @Jonasw got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way is to reorganize your code to build the result array directly while looping over the `rowObject`:

```
function convertObjectToArray(columnIndexes, rowObject) {
  let res = [];
  for(let key in rowObject)
    if(columnIndexes.indexOf(+key) < 0)
      res.push(rowObject[key]);
  return res;
}
```

Working demo code in the snippet below:

```js
let excludeColumns = [2, 4, 5];
let rowObject= {
 '0': 'value 0',
 '1': 'value 1',
 '2': 'value 2',
 '3': 'value 3',
 '4': 'value 4',
 '5': 'value 5',
 '6': 'value 6'
};

console.log(
  convertObjectToArray(excludeColumns, rowObject)
);

function convertObjectToArray(columnIndexes, rowObject) {
  let res = [];
  for(let key in rowObject)
    if(columnIndexes.indexOf(+key) < 0)
      res.push(rowObject[key]);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const convertObjectToArray = (columnIndexes, rowObject) =>
  Object.keys(rowObject)
   .filter( key => columnIndexes.includes(+key))
   .map(key => rowObject[key])
```

Or if you really want empty strings:

```
const convertObjectToArray = (columnIndexes, rowObject) =>
  Object.entries(rowObject)
   .map(([key, value]) =>
     columnIndexes.includes(+key)
     ?value
     :""
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution very close to what you were working with:

```
const convertObjectToArray = (columnIndexes, rowObject) => {
    return Object.keys(rowObject).map(key => {
        let rowValue = '';
        if (columnIndexes.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            rowValue = rowObject[key];
        } 
        return rowValue;        
    });
};
```